# How to deform mesh with 2 empties?

Tags: animation, rigging

this is kind of long and I’m sort of a newbie so bare with me.

So I have a flight stick that I’m trying to animate.

In my game, you need two empties or armatures, one to move the stick forward and back and one to move it sideways. Using empties you have to parent the empties to the object; the forward-back empty parents the side to side empty which parents the object.

In addition to animating the stick I also have to deform a mesh that surrounds it so I tried using two armatures, parenting them to my object with automatic weights. For some reason, when my object is parented by armatures it disappears in the game (which doesn’t happen with empties), so I had to unparent it while keeping the modifier.

With these steps I’m able to get the forward back movement to work, but the side to side movement is unresponsive. I can use empties with no problem getting both forward-back and side-side movements to work but deforming the mesh to my knowledge, requires armatures.

Below I have 2 examples. One using empties and one using armatures. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

With empties:
https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/xmSR9gtdrhB0Uq2zoIAwkK1OBk2.blend

With armatures:
https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/cayoIKnaSPpEiHr08uTChc0um0E.blend

Comment: can you pls add images/sketches/animations/links  1) what you want it to look like 2) how it looks now - this will attract more people to help you instead of opening two blender files

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.